# Why some processes(even they are user processes) could not be migrated to a certain cpu by `cpuset(7)`?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, cgroups, cpuset

Why some processes could not be migrated to a certain cpu by `cpuset(7)` while some processes could?

I found that these processes could not be really migrated to a certain cpu(**Though when you check the `cpuset` filesystem,it seems ok.But if check the affinity of these processes by `top` or `htop`, you could find the `cpuset` does not work for these processes indeed.**):

```
     /sbin/init splash
     /usr/sbin/rpc.idmapd
     /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
     /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
     /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
     /usr/sbin/sshd -D
     /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf 
     /var/run/dhclient-
     /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-
     sshd: john [priv]
     sshd: john [priv]
     sshd: john@notty
     /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
     lightdm --session-child 12 15
     upstart-file-bridge --daemon --user
     /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes
     /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
     /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-addre
     /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
     /usr/lib/update-notifier/system-crash-notification
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service
     /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-printers/indicator-printers-service
     /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry
     /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry
     /usr/lib/colord/colord
     /usr/lib/colord/colord
     /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
     /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
     /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-fallback-mount-helper
     /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
     /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
     /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd --no-debug
     /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
     /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess --factory contacts --bus-name or
     zeitgeist-datahub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that may because your computer use [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) model rather than [SMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing) model. This can solve the problem, but I'm not sure if that is the reason.

Comment: How can i know  which model does the computer use？

Comment: It's easy to google, I think you should do it yourserlf rather than ask me. But [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/numactl) it is.

Comment: It is tested on personal computer.So i think it's SMP model. **Some user processes could be  migrated to a certain cpu by cpuset(7) indeed.**